# Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `db`:`5432` on github actions

Tags: postgresql, next.js, docker-compose, github-actions, prisma

Im using a docker-compose.yml file to set up a postgreSQL database service and a web application that uses that database. I need to set them both up to run a end-to-end test with cypress.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:12"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    env_file:
      - .env
  app:
    image: "coinly-app"
    build:
      context: ./
      target: production
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

.github/workflows/tests.yml

```
name: Testing the web application

on: push

jobs:
  testing:
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04
    environment: testing
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        
      - name: Installing dependencies
        run: |
          npm ci

      - name: Unit tests
        run: npm run test

      - name: Create env file
        run: |
          touch .env
          echo 'DATABASE_URL=${{ secrets.DATABASE_URL }}' >> .env
          echo 'AUTH_SECRET=${{ secrets.AUTH_SECRET }}' >> .env
          echo 'AUTH_URL=${{ secrets.AUTH_URL }}' >> .env
          cat .env

      - name: Set up web application
        run: |
          docker-compose up --build -d
          docker ps -a
          npx prisma migrate dev --name init
          npx prisma db seed
        
      - name: End-to-end tests
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
        with:
          browser: chrome
        env:
          # pass GitHub token to detect new build vs re-run build
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN}}
```

This is my DATABASE_URL
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://:@db:5432/coinly-db?schema=public"

This all works well locally, running docker-compose up works perfectly but it does not work on github actions. I've looked at many other similar issues posted by other people but I do not see what I am doing wrong.

I've tried changing the hostname on the postgres URI from localhost to db

https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/14187
[Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `localhost`:`5200`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71251937/error-p1001-cant-reach-database-server-at-localhost5200?rq=2)

This is also the docker ps -a output from github actions
[docker ps -a output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oyFa.png)

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED                  STATUS                  PORTS                                       NAMES
c5c06bd2bf10   coinly-app    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   Less than a second ago   Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp   coinly_app_1
8689b4634305   postgres:12   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   Less than a second ago   Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   coinly_db_1

Full GitHub actions workflow

```
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2408211Z Current runner version: '2.314.1'
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2431119Z ##[group]Operating System
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2431925Z Ubuntu
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2432285Z 22.04.4
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2432838Z LTS
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2433201Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2433621Z ##[group]Runner Image
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2434153Z Image: ubuntu-22.04
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2434527Z Version: 20240324.2.0
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2435523Z Included Software: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/ubuntu22/20240324.2/images/ubuntu/Ubuntu2204-Readme.md
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2437052Z Image Release: https://github.com/actions/runner-images/releases/tag/ubuntu22%2F20240324.2
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2437929Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2438345Z ##[group]Runner Image Provisioner
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2438935Z 2.0.361.1
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2439287Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2440355Z ##[group]GITHUB_TOKEN Permissions
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2441893Z Contents: read
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2442355Z Metadata: read
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2443062Z Packages: read
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2443639Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2446685Z Secret source: Actions
2024-04-01T12:47:22.2447403Z Prepare workflow directory
2024-04-01T12:47:22.3067013Z Prepare all required actions
2024-04-01T12:47:22.3225444Z Getting action download info
2024-04-01T12:47:22.5135913Z Download action repository 'actions/checkout@v4' (SHA:b4ffde65f46336ab88eb53be808477a3936bae11)
2024-04-01T12:47:22.6187359Z Download action repository 'cypress-io/github-action@v6' (SHA:1b70233146622b69e789ccdd4f9452adc638d25a)
2024-04-01T12:47:23.9158196Z Complete job name: testing
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0101075Z ##[group]Run actions/checkout@v4
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0101741Z with:
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0102192Z   repository: ZhnYng/coinly
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0103032Z   token: ***
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0103460Z   ssh-strict: true
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0103929Z   persist-credentials: true
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0104511Z   clean: true
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0104966Z   sparse-checkout-cone-mode: true
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0105622Z   fetch-depth: 1
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0106045Z   fetch-tags: false
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0106506Z   show-progress: true
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0106977Z   lfs: false
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0107371Z   submodules: false
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0107840Z   set-safe-directory: true
2024-04-01T12:47:24.0108382Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1709208Z Syncing repository: ZhnYng/coinly
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1711878Z ##[group]Getting Git version info
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1713319Z Working directory is '/home/runner/work/coinly/coinly'
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1714981Z [command]/usr/bin/git version
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1716049Z git version 2.43.2
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1718775Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1734451Z Temporarily overriding HOME='/home/runner/work/_temp/bcbe5ecc-aeea-4198-aab1-d359e232d3f4' before making global git config changes
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1737080Z Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1739256Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --global --add safe.directory /home/runner/work/coinly/coinly
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1742239Z Deleting the contents of '/home/runner/work/coinly/coinly'
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1747428Z ##[group]Initializing the repository
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1749619Z [command]/usr/bin/git init /home/runner/work/coinly/coinly
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1803600Z hint: Using 'master' as the name for the initial branch. This default branch name
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1805519Z hint: is subject to change. To configure the initial branch name to use in all
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1807415Z hint: of your new repositories, which will suppress this warning, call:
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1808793Z hint: 
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1809893Z hint:  git config --global init.defaultBranch <name>
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1810899Z hint: 
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1812255Z hint: Names commonly chosen instead of 'master' are 'main', 'trunk' and
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1814280Z hint: 'development'. The just-created branch can be renamed via this command:
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1815531Z hint: 
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1816728Z hint:  git branch -m <name>
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1817967Z Initialized empty Git repository in /home/runner/work/coinly/coinly/.git/
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1820999Z [command]/usr/bin/git remote add origin https://github.com/ZhnYng/coinly
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1856501Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1858449Z ##[group]Disabling automatic garbage collection
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1860332Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local gc.auto 0
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1894660Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1896533Z ##[group]Setting up auth
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1900285Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp core\.sshCommand
2024-04-01T12:47:24.1932702Z [command]/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'core\.sshCommand' && git config --local --unset-all 'core.sshCommand' || :"
2024-04-01T12:47:24.2236967Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader
2024-04-01T12:47:24.2264815Z [command]/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader' && git config --local --unset-all 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' || :"
2024-04-01T12:47:24.2503424Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local http.https://github.com/.extraheader AUTHORIZATION: basic ***
2024-04-01T12:47:24.2537428Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:24.2538914Z ##[group]Fetching the repository
2024-04-01T12:47:24.2547614Z [command]/usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --no-tags --prune --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin +b2af584df9f0db3e2e405894571e95e3ba3526ad:refs/remotes/origin/CI
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8213342Z From https://github.com/ZhnYng/coinly
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8214976Z  * [new ref]         b2af584df9f0db3e2e405894571e95e3ba3526ad -> origin/CI
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8237941Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8238624Z ##[group]Determining the checkout info
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8240364Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8241121Z ##[group]Checking out the ref
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8244999Z [command]/usr/bin/git checkout --progress --force -B CI refs/remotes/origin/CI
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8360925Z Switched to a new branch 'CI'
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8375918Z branch 'CI' set up to track 'origin/CI'.
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8380944Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8401731Z [command]/usr/bin/git log -1 --format='%H'
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8425959Z 'b2af584df9f0db3e2e405894571e95e3ba3526ad'
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8728031Z ##[group]Run npm ci
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8728502Z [36;1mnpm ci[0m
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8767398Z shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
2024-04-01T12:47:24.8767863Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:36.1326163Z npm WARN deprecated abab@2.0.6: Use your platform's native atob() and btoa() methods instead
2024-04-01T12:47:36.2726439Z npm WARN deprecated domexception@4.0.0: Use your platform's native DOMException instead
2024-04-01T12:47:54.3391510Z 
2024-04-01T12:47:54.3392406Z added 886 packages, and audited 887 packages in 26s
2024-04-01T12:47:54.3393112Z 
2024-04-01T12:47:54.3393388Z 191 packages are looking for funding
2024-04-01T12:47:54.3394141Z   run `npm fund` for details
2024-04-01T12:47:54.3412433Z 
2024-04-01T12:47:54.3412711Z found 0 vulnerabilities
2024-04-01T12:47:54.3868364Z ##[group]Run npm run test
2024-04-01T12:47:54.3868710Z [36;1mnpm run test[0m
2024-04-01T12:47:54.3892391Z shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
2024-04-01T12:47:54.3892700Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:54.6708027Z 
2024-04-01T12:47:54.6708409Z > coinly@0.1.0 test
2024-04-01T12:47:54.6708918Z > jest
2024-04-01T12:47:54.6709161Z 
2024-04-01T12:47:58.1267423Z PASS app/lib/__tests__/utils.test.ts
2024-04-01T12:47:58.4087088Z PASS app/__tests__/Home.test.tsx
2024-04-01T12:47:58.4686155Z 
2024-04-01T12:47:58.4690405Z Test Suites: 2 passed, 2 total
2024-04-01T12:47:58.4691024Z Tests:       20 passed, 20 total
2024-04-01T12:47:58.4691557Z Snapshots:   0 total
2024-04-01T12:47:58.4691986Z Time:        1.441 s
2024-04-01T12:47:58.4692587Z Ran all test suites.
2024-04-01T12:47:58.5247776Z ##[group]Run touch .env
2024-04-01T12:47:58.5248602Z [36;1mtouch .env[0m
2024-04-01T12:47:58.5249883Z [36;1mecho 'DATABASE_URL=***' >> .env[0m
2024-04-01T12:47:58.5250879Z [36;1mecho 'AUTH_SECRET=***' >> .env[0m
2024-04-01T12:47:58.5251693Z [36;1mecho 'AUTH_URL=***' >> .env[0m
2024-04-01T12:47:58.5252246Z [36;1mcat .env[0m
2024-04-01T12:47:58.5278085Z shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
2024-04-01T12:47:58.5278398Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:47:58.7674108Z DATABASE_URL=***
2024-04-01T12:47:58.7680039Z AUTH_SECRET=***
2024-04-01T12:47:58.7680680Z AUTH_URL=***
2024-04-01T12:47:58.7711363Z ##[group]Run docker-compose up --build -d
2024-04-01T12:47:58.7711820Z [36;1mdocker-compose up --build -d[0m
2024-04-01T12:47:58.7712172Z [36;1mdocker ps -a[0m
2024-04-01T12:47:58.7712438Z [36;1mcat .env[0m
2024-04-01T12:47:58.7712729Z [36;1mnpx prisma migrate dev --name init[0m
2024-04-01T12:47:58.7713185Z [36;1mnpx prisma db seed[0m
2024-04-01T12:47:58.7737493Z shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
2024-04-01T12:47:58.7737797Z ##[endgroup]
2024-04-01T12:48:00.7718373Z Creating network "coinly_coinly_network" with driver "bridge"
2024-04-01T12:48:00.8458966Z Pulling db (postgres:12)...
2024-04-01T12:48:01.8581066Z 12: Pulling from library/postgres
2024-04-01T12:48:08.4452143Z Digest: sha256:7206ad3a83977749e09f9ac1e7ef41f70b2652fdcbce73994eeaf446b9da327b
2024-04-01T12:48:08.4464445Z Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:12
2024-04-01T12:48:08.4476911Z Building app
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2355391Z #0 building with "default" instance using docker driver
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2356052Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2356247Z #1 [internal] load .dockerignore
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2356803Z #1 transferring context: 2B done
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2357312Z #1 DONE 0.0s
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2370017Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2371475Z #2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2372234Z #2 transferring dockerfile: 758B done
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2372821Z #2 DONE 0.0s
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2373349Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2374478Z #3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18-alpine
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2375469Z #3 DONE 0.0s
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2375745Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2376174Z #4 [base 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/node:18-alpine
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2376832Z #4 DONE 0.0s
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2377065Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:11.2377264Z #5 [internal] load build context
2024-04-01T12:48:16.1652996Z #5 transferring context: 441.87MB 5.0s
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4626373Z #5 ...
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4627092Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4628804Z #6 [base 2/4] RUN apk add --no-cache g++ make py3-pip libc6-compat
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4630979Z #6 1.034 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4633243Z #6 1.546 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4635105Z #6 1.936 (1/41) Installing libstdc++-dev (13.2.1_git20231014-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4636251Z #6 2.142 (2/41) Installing jansson (2.14-r4)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4637270Z #6 2.144 (3/41) Installing zstd-libs (1.5.5-r8)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4638276Z #6 2.155 (4/41) Installing binutils (2.41-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4639366Z #6 2.257 (5/41) Installing libgomp (13.2.1_git20231014-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4640514Z #6 2.263 (6/41) Installing libatomic (13.2.1_git20231014-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4641478Z #6 2.266 (7/41) Installing gmp (6.3.0-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4642329Z #6 2.272 (8/41) Installing isl26 (0.26-r1)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4643235Z #6 2.290 (9/41) Installing mpfr4 (4.2.1-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4683082Z #6 2.299 (10/41) Installing mpc1 (1.3.1-r1)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4684287Z #6 2.302 (11/41) Installing gcc (13.2.1_git20231014-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4685851Z #6 3.314 (12/41) Installing musl-dev (1.2.4_git20230717-r4)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4686840Z #6 3.441 (13/41) Installing libc-dev (0.7.2-r5)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4687716Z #6 3.444 (14/41) Installing g++ (13.2.1_git20231014-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4688593Z #6 3.716 (15/41) Installing musl-obstack (1.2.3-r2)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4689439Z #6 3.719 (16/41) Installing libucontext (1.2-r2)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4690613Z #6 3.721 (17/41) Installing gcompat (1.1.0-r4)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4691409Z #6 3.725 (18/41) Installing make (4.4.1-r2)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4692174Z #6 3.731 (19/41) Installing libbz2 (1.0.8-r6)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4692951Z #6 3.733 (20/41) Installing libexpat (2.6.2-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4694213Z #6 3.737 (21/41) Installing libffi (3.4.4-r3)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4694996Z #6 3.739 (22/41) Installing gdbm (1.23-r1)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4696109Z #6 3.743 (23/41) Installing xz-libs (5.4.5-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4696955Z #6 3.747 (24/41) Installing mpdecimal (2.5.1-r2)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4697948Z #6 3.752 (25/41) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.4_p20231125-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4699010Z #6 3.779 (26/41) Installing libncursesw (6.4_p20231125-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4700279Z #6 3.784 (27/41) Installing libpanelw (6.4_p20231125-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4701170Z #6 3.786 (28/41) Installing readline (8.2.1-r2)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4701997Z #6 3.791 (29/41) Installing sqlite-libs (3.44.2-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4702859Z #6 3.808 (30/41) Installing python3 (3.11.8-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4703783Z #6 4.171 (31/41) Installing python3-pycache-pyc0 (3.11.8-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4704660Z #6 4.406 (32/41) Installing pyc (3.11.8-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4705523Z #6 4.409 (33/41) Installing py3-setuptools-pyc (68.2.2-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4706458Z #6 4.486 (34/41) Installing py3-pip-pyc (23.3.1-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4707312Z #6 4.725 (35/41) Installing py3-parsing (3.1.1-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4708211Z #6 4.732 (36/41) Installing py3-parsing-pyc (3.1.1-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4709129Z #6 4.741 (37/41) Installing py3-packaging-pyc (23.2-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4710019Z #6 4.748 (38/41) Installing python3-pyc (3.11.8-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4710901Z #6 4.749 (39/41) Installing py3-packaging (23.2-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4711797Z #6 4.758 (40/41) Installing py3-setuptools (68.2.2-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4712646Z #6 4.808 (41/41) Installing py3-pip (23.3.1-r0)
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4713459Z #6 5.001 Executing busybox-1.36.1-r15.trigger
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4714111Z #6 5.027 OK: 282 MiB in 58 packages
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4714711Z #6 DONE 7.3s
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4714968Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:18.4715144Z #7 [base 3/4] WORKDIR /app
2024-04-01T12:48:18.8682329Z #7 DONE 0.3s
2024-04-01T12:48:18.8683022Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:18.8683441Z #5 [internal] load build context
2024-04-01T12:48:19.4749758Z #5 transferring context: 660.39MB 8.1s done
2024-04-01T12:48:19.4750441Z #5 DONE 8.2s
2024-04-01T12:48:19.4750700Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:19.4750944Z #8 [base 4/4] COPY package*.json ./
2024-04-01T12:48:19.6593534Z #8 DONE 0.3s
2024-04-01T12:48:19.8230031Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:19.8230546Z #9 [builder 1/4] WORKDIR /app
2024-04-01T12:48:19.8231115Z #9 DONE 0.0s
2024-04-01T12:48:19.8231364Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:19.8231526Z #10 [builder 2/4] COPY . .
2024-04-01T12:48:26.2142254Z #10 DONE 6.5s
2024-04-01T12:48:26.2142858Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:26.2143228Z #11 [production 2/9] RUN npx prisma generate
2024-04-01T12:48:26.3658983Z #11 ...
2024-04-01T12:48:26.3659345Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:26.3662113Z #12 [builder 3/4] RUN npm i
2024-04-01T12:48:42.0512508Z #12 ...
2024-04-01T12:48:42.0512832Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:42.0513117Z #11 [production 2/9] RUN npx prisma generate
2024-04-01T12:48:42.2010865Z #11 22.38 npm WARN exec The following package was not found and will be installed: prisma@5.11.0
2024-04-01T12:48:42.5791047Z #11 ...
2024-04-01T12:48:42.5792453Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:42.5799822Z #12 [builder 3/4] RUN npm i
2024-04-01T12:48:42.5800389Z #12 16.17 
2024-04-01T12:48:42.5800944Z #12 16.17 up to date, audited 887 packages in 4s
2024-04-01T12:48:42.5801606Z #12 16.17 
2024-04-01T12:48:42.5802105Z #12 16.17 191 packages are looking for funding
2024-04-01T12:48:42.5802880Z #12 16.17   run `npm fund` for details
2024-04-01T12:48:42.5803455Z #12 16.17 
2024-04-01T12:48:42.5803875Z #12 16.17 found 0 vulnerabilities
2024-04-01T12:48:42.5804403Z #12 DONE 16.4s
2024-04-01T12:48:42.7305413Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:42.7306212Z #13 [builder 4/4] RUN npm run build
2024-04-01T12:48:43.4680745Z #13 0.887 
2024-04-01T12:48:43.4681300Z #13 0.887 > coinly@0.1.0 build
2024-04-01T12:48:43.4682129Z #13 0.887 > next build
2024-04-01T12:48:43.4682601Z #13 0.887 
2024-04-01T12:48:44.8002680Z #13 2.220 Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
2024-04-01T12:48:44.9033193Z #13 2.221 This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
2024-04-01T12:48:44.9035620Z #13 2.221 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
2024-04-01T12:48:44.9037129Z #13 2.221 https://nextjs.org/telemetry
2024-04-01T12:48:44.9037677Z #13 2.221 
2024-04-01T12:48:44.9038944Z #13 2.323    ▲ Next.js 14.1.0
2024-04-01T12:48:45.1419590Z #13 2.323    - Environments: .env
2024-04-01T12:48:45.1420249Z #13 2.323 
2024-04-01T12:48:45.1420813Z #13 2.411    Creating an optimized production build ...
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6703962Z #13 ...
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6704347Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6704653Z #11 [production 2/9] RUN npx prisma generate
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6705731Z #11 25.85 prisma:warn We could not find your Prisma schema at `prisma/schema.prisma`.
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6707102Z #11 25.85 If you have a Prisma schema file in a custom path, you will need to run
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6708958Z #11 25.85 `prisma generate --schema=./path/to/your/schema.prisma` to generate Prisma Client.
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6710575Z #11 25.85 If you do not have a Prisma schema file yet, you can ignore this message.
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6711586Z #11 25.85 
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6711955Z #11 25.88 npm notice 
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6712783Z #11 25.88 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.2.4 -> 10.5.0
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6713930Z #11 25.88 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.5.0>
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6715097Z #11 25.88 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.5.0` to update!
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6715818Z #11 25.88 npm notice 
2024-04-01T12:48:45.6716246Z #11 DONE 26.0s
2024-04-01T12:48:45.8206049Z 
2024-04-01T12:48:45.8206580Z #13 [builder 4/4] RUN npm run build
2024-04-01T12:48:59.6449982Z #13 17.06  ✓ Compiled successfully
2024-04-01T12:48:59.7963743Z #13 17.07    Linting and checking validity of types ...
2024-04-01T12:49:06.3859049Z #13 23.81    Collecting page data ...
2024-04-01T12:49:08.0688172Z #13 25.49    Generating static pages (0/9) ...
2024-04-01T12:49:08.3387245Z #13 25.76 
2024-04-01T12:49:08.3387814Z    Generating static pages (2/9) 
2024-04-01T12:49:08.5392217Z #13 25.77 
2024-04-01T12:49:08.5392825Z    Generating static pages (4/9) 
2024-04-01T12:49:08.5393381Z #13 25.85 
2024-04-01T12:49:08.5393786Z    Generating static pages (6/9) 
2024-04-01T12:49:08.5450536Z #13 25.96 
2024-04-01T12:49:08.5451299Z  ✓ Generating static pages (9/9) 
2024-04-01T12:49:08.8756417Z #13 26.30    Finalizing page optimization ...
2024-04-01T12:49:08.8757106Z #13 26.30    Collecting build traces ...
2024-04-01T12:49:14.7164011Z #13 32.14 
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8470573Z #13 32.19 Route (app)                              Size     First Load JS
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8471980Z #13 32.19 ┌ ○ /                                    901 B          85.1 kB
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8473023Z #13 32.19 ├ ○ /_not-found                          882 B          85.1 kB
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8474044Z #13 32.19 ├ ○ /login                               2.55 kB          94 kB
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8477372Z #13 32.19 ├ ○ /signup                              2.62 kB          94 kB
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8479231Z #13 32.19 ├ λ /transactions                        1.33 kB        97.5 kB
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8510370Z #13 32.19 ├ λ /transactions/[id]/edit              2.92 kB        94.3 kB
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8512125Z #13 32.19 └ ○ /transactions/create                 2.9 kB         94.3 kB
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8513493Z #13 32.19 + First Load JS shared by all            84.2 kB
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8514643Z #13 32.19   ├ chunks/69-b2c4d077e15606ae.js        28.9 kB
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8515961Z #13 32.19   ├ chunks/fd9d1056-a5bfbc7ee16649a9.js  53.4 kB
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8517770Z #13 32.19   └ other shared chunks (total)          1.9 kB
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8518669Z #13 32.19 
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8519242Z #13 32.19 
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8520134Z #13 32.19 ƒ Middleware                             139 kB
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8521012Z #13 32.19 
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8521818Z #13 32.19 ○  (Static)   prerendered as static content
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8523013Z #13 32.19 λ  (Dynamic)  server-rendered on demand using Node.js
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8524436Z #13 32.19 
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8525024Z #13 32.21 npm notice 
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8526111Z #13 32.21 npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.2.4 -> 10.5.0
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8527626Z #13 32.22 npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.5.0>
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8529203Z #13 32.22 npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.5.0` to update!
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8530147Z #13 32.22 npm notice 
2024-04-01T12:49:14.8530784Z #13 DONE 32.3s
2024-04-01T12:49:18.3492593Z 
2024-04-01T12:49:18.3494871Z #14 [production 3/9] COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next ./.next
2024-04-01T12:49:18.5499618Z #14 DONE 0.2s
2024-04-01T12:49:18.7010869Z 
2024-04-01T12:49:18.7012145Z #15 [production 4/9] COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules ./node_modules
2024-04-01T12:49:24.8490657Z #15 DONE 6.3s
2024-04-01T12:49:25.0256199Z 
2024-04-01T12:49:25.0257539Z #16 [production 5/9] COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json
2024-04-01T12:49:25.0258583Z #16 DONE 0.0s
2024-04-01T12:49:25.0258883Z 
2024-04-01T12:49:25.0259802Z #17 [production 6/9] COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
2024-04-01T12:49:25.0260563Z #17 DONE 0.0s
2024-04-01T12:49:25.0260810Z 
2024-04-01T12:49:25.0261208Z #18 [production 7/9] RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
2024-04-01T12:49:25.0433453Z #18 DONE 0.2s
2024-04-01T12:49:25.1958344Z 
2024-04-01T12:49:25.1959279Z #19 [production 8/9] RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001
2024-04-01T12:49:25.3329914Z #19 DONE 0.3s
2024-04-01T12:49:25.4867868Z 
2024-04-01T12:49:25.4868853Z #20 [production 9/9] RUN chown -R nextjs:nodejs /app/.next
2024-04-01T12:49:25.8240132Z #20 DONE 0.5s
2024-04-01T12:49:25.9754818Z 
2024-04-01T12:49:25.9757045Z #21 exporting to image
2024-04-01T12:49:25.9757814Z #21 exporting layers
2024-04-01T12:49:35.1011612Z #21 exporting layers 9.3s done
2024-04-01T12:49:35.1292204Z #21 writing image sha256:c9dfe7dd6de203ce2ec45e28914240b973dbb5b2b1c4e8ddae19003501eb761d done
2024-04-01T12:49:35.1293897Z #21 naming to docker.io/library/coinly-app done
2024-04-01T12:49:35.1294470Z #21 DONE 9.3s
2024-04-01T12:49:35.1516864Z Creating coinly_app_1 ... 
2024-04-01T12:49:35.1539981Z Creating coinly_db_1  ... 
2024-04-01T12:49:35.6183540Z Creating coinly_app_1 ... done
2024-04-01T12:49:35.6189131Z Creating coinly_db_1  ... done
2024-04-01T12:49:35.7097245Z CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND                  CREATED                  STATUS                  PORTS                                       NAMES
2024-04-01T12:49:35.7115894Z 217d33c5d603   postgres:12   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   Less than a second ago   Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   coinly_db_1
2024-04-01T12:49:35.7118545Z 9716d5763029   coinly-app    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   Less than a second ago   Up Less than a second   0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp, :::3000->3000/tcp   coinly_app_1
2024-04-01T12:49:35.7144883Z DATABASE_URL=***
2024-04-01T12:49:35.7145578Z AUTH_SECRET=***
2024-04-01T12:49:35.7146095Z AUTH_URL=***
2024-04-01T12:49:36.9176216Z Environment variables loaded from .env
2024-04-01T12:49:36.9180745Z Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
2024-04-01T12:49:36.9210423Z Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "coinly-db", schema "public" at "db:5432"
2024-04-01T12:49:36.9211512Z 
2024-04-01T12:49:37.6036327Z Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `db`:`5432`
2024-04-01T12:49:37.6037053Z 
2024-04-01T12:49:37.6037527Z Please make sure your database server is running at `db`:`5432`.
2024-04-01T12:49:37.6237110Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
2024-04-01T12:49:37.6335866Z Post job cleanup.
2024-04-01T12:49:37.7049898Z [command]/usr/bin/git version
2024-04-01T12:49:37.7090476Z git version 2.43.2
2024-04-01T12:49:37.7133406Z Temporarily overriding HOME='/home/runner/work/_temp/b80839f0-049d-4735-976a-4ba9f455d73a' before making global git config changes
2024-04-01T12:49:37.7135329Z Adding repository directory to the temporary git global config as a safe directory
2024-04-01T12:49:37.7139248Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --global --add safe.directory /home/runner/work/coinly/coinly
2024-04-01T12:49:37.7173785Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp core\.sshCommand
2024-04-01T12:49:37.7206101Z [command]/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'core\.sshCommand' && git config --local --unset-all 'core.sshCommand' || :"
2024-04-01T12:49:37.7457939Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader
2024-04-01T12:49:37.7478193Z http.https://github.com/.extraheader
2024-04-01T12:49:37.7489034Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --unset-all http.https://github.com/.extraheader
2024-04-01T12:49:37.7519018Z [command]/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive sh -c "git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader' && git config --local --unset-all 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' || :"
2024-04-01T12:49:37.7985634Z Cleaning up orphan processes
```

Comment: Does cat .env prints all your environment variables? 

Also, can you do logs <Container_Name> for the detailed logs, please

Comment: Hi @deepbajaj thanks for the response. Yes cat .env does print all my environment variables.

Comment: Hi @Azeem thanks for the response. Yes the docker-compose.yml file is the same as what I use locally.

Comment: @user15459512 I mean can you try to do cat .env in this step `-- name: Set up web application`